# Wordpress JSON API only working when logged in

Tags: wordpress, authentication, wordpress-rest-api

I seem to be only able to access the wordpress json api when I am logged in in wordpress (no matter which endpoint, even on `GET mypage.com/wp-json/`). When I remove all cookies or logout and call the endpoint I get redirected to the login-screen. 
Is this the desired behavior when I do not use nonces?

This happens on our staging environment, on our live-page everything works, I get results from the JSON API even if I am not logged in.

We created the staging site with the plugin from https://wp-staging.com/
So maybe there is a setting missing which has not been copied over? Or can I turn off checking for authentication / nonces on the API somewhere in the wordpress settings?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the WP Staging Plugin has an option to limit access to the staging page which is set to "Administrators" by default. Turned it to "Allow access from all" and now it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On a WP website that I was asked to work on - it took me a lot of hours on debugging my own code (initially), then to start investigating the theme and finally deeper in other plugins and wp-core...

After all that, I found that the plugin members has functionality to restrict the rest_api access only to logged-in users.

There is a setting for this in the settings page of the plugin.

> REST API -> Require authentication for access to the REST API.

So, I am posting this here, in case it could help someone else to avoid the same headache I encountered with this.